# How does one Raycast from under the cursor/mouse in 2D in Godot?

Tags: c#, game-engine, godot, raycasting, godot4

I belong to the Unity-crowd shuffling over here and loving what I see :) I couldn't find much on this online so wanted to ask, and maybe it will help someone else in the future.

I added a Area2D node with a child that is a CollisionShape2D (that holds a circle shape)
I made a RayCast2D-node in my scene.
I added a script to it I call "CheckUnderCursor".
In it, [based on the documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) (but adjusting the "Create"-attributes passed to be mouse-cursor positions) (but adjusting the "Create"-attributes passed to be mouse-cursor positions)

```
​

    public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {
        var spaceState = GetWorld2D().DirectSpaceState;
        // use global coordinates, not local to node
        var query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters2D.Create(GetViewport().GetMousePosition(), GetViewport().GetMousePosition() );
        var result = spaceState.IntersectRay(query);
        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            GD.Print(result);
        }
    }
```

However, hovering my cursor over where I know the collider is doesn't print any hits. I was wondering if anyone knows where I'm going wrong, and how to correctly raycast straight from the cursor in Godot 2D? :) My suspicion is I'm giving the wrong "to"-position to the Create, but I don't know what value I should give instead in 2D-space.

Thanks so much in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

In general you do not need to do this, since you can set the `input_pickable` property of the `Area2D` to `true`, and then override the `_input_event` or connect to the `input_event` signal. There are also `mouse_entered` and `mouse_exited` signals.

With that said, sometimes you need to query by other means...

Now a couple things:

- You want the position in global coordinates (i.e. coordinates of the 2D world, in this case), not viewport coordinates.
- You do not want to intersect a ray, you want to intersect a point.

```
var spaceState = GetWorld2D().DirectSpaceState;
var query = new PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D();
query.position = GetGlobalMousePosition();
var result = spaceState.intersect_point(query);
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    GD.Print(result);
}
```

By the way, if you need to debug your colliders, you might enable "Visible Collision Shapes" in the "Debug" menu.

I hope that helps.